# Can anyone tell me that why the {For} Loop in JavaScript is returning all the values including the very first element of the an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, console.log

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

I ran this code on google chrome console and the output was like this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

In this code I can see that all the elements are been printed but the very first element of the array which is 1 **should not** print because the value of **[i]** has already been incremented to 1 and so 2 should be printed instead of 1.
**Can someone tell me why is this happening ?**

Comment: `i++` happens *after* the loop body, not before it.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on how `for` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting it wrong here. In for loop, we have

```
for(initialization, condition, change) {
 // body
}
```

So, it workes in this sequence

initialization -> condition -> body -> change

PS: It will go to body if condition evaluates to `true`